# Are there any opensource C# libraries for calculating bond duration and other FI Analytics?

Tags: fixed-income, programming, duration, yield

I'm doing some Fixed Income analytics work and wanted to know if there where any opensource C# libraries that I could use in order to avoid writing functions for generic calculations like YTM and Duration.

Thanks for the help,
Rafael

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Quantlib.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qlnet/)?  We use it both in the back office and some soft realtime trading system for pricing bonds.

There are a few questions on this site that deal with using it for pricing bonds.

See here:

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantlib+bond